# Filled a wchar array element with same value

Tags: c++

I have a `wchar_t a[1000]` array.

I want to fill the array element with the same value:

```
a[0]= 'w', a[1]= 'w',...a[999] = 'w'.
```

Are there any fast way to do this?

(without using for loop to assign each value)

Comment: why you want to do a thing like that?

Comment: I want to init / modify a array element with the same value

Comment: do you mean `wchar_t`?

Comment: yes, wchar_t. I fixed it

Comment: @reiko: define fast? Fast for you, the programmer? Fast for the computer to execute? Fast in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use std::fill from algorithm

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main(){
    std::array<wchar, 1000> a;
    std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 'w');

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `std::array<wchar, 1000> not_a_reserved_name;`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb It ensures default initialization... I have been taught to use it wherever I declare a variable to ensure it is initialized to avoid undefined behaviour. Not quite sure it is best practice...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i just used the example of reiko. But yes i should use another variable name

Comment: @user2393256 His sample was already correct: _"I have a `wchar a[1000]`."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh i got that wrong... i corrected my example code

Comment: std::fill uses a while loop as well... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/

Comment: @GézaTörök that reference page is saying that the effect of fill is equivalent to that loop, however the compiler may optimize the procedure

Comment: @MattMcNabb Okay, thanks for your input. I changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In GCC you can use

```
wchar_t a[1000] = {[0 ... 999] = 'w'};
```

Comment: But in other compilers, you should hand-write all those 'w''s because C++ meta-programming is on level 0.

Comment: Solvable with defines. Take a look at what is available in boost.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a global, and initialize it with 'w''s. Sorry for the fact that you should do that manually but ISO C++ doesn't like meta-programming.

```
wchar_t a[1000] { 'w', 'w' /*............*/ };
```

This is the fastest way as array data will be directly copied into memory when program is loaded.

Comment: Why _Declare it as a global_ please?

Comment: Because as I said - it's the fastest way because it will be directly loaded into memory.

Comment: I don't get it, advising global variables isn't very wise, and the initializer syntax, works well for stack variables as well. Also note there needs only a single initializer `'W'`, that is used for all the rest of the array.

Comment: Global are just copied into process memory at program load-time with the program code. Writing in a function will produce additional code and should allocate and de-allocate space on the stack.

Comment: both are equivalent, the compiler may optimize either way depending on what optimization switches you provide

Answer (score 0):

The most compact way I can think of is to use `std::vector` - one of its constructors is doing exactly what you want (it may use a loop internally though):

```
std::vector<wchar_t> a(1000, 'w');
```